# Python. The code is outputting the wrong answer. Math related

Tags: python

```
    def compound_interest(principle, time, rate):
    
        amount = principle * (pow((1 + rate / 100), time))
        return amount - principle

print('The compound interest is: ', compound_interest(10000, 10.25, 5))
```

The output should be 6288.946267774416 but I am getting 6488.848034974573. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are accidentally **reversing your time and rate arguments** when calling it.

You should be calling it as:

```
compound_interest(10000, 5, 10.25)
```

not `compound_interest(10000, 10.25, 5)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should “accept” the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  __This is not a forum. If you wish to thank somebody, you should [vote him up](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up).__ We require a little bit of [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) before you can do that to prevent abuse; why don't you get some by [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)?